# Forward logs in linux to remote syslog server

Tags: syslog, logs

I need to forward logs from the below OS to a remote syslog server. I am trying to browser google to find some info. Will you please help me change the configuration so that even if the system reboot I am able to send message to the server? OS are:

Ubuntu from 10.04 to 18.04 (LTS) Debian 5.04 Fedora 10 CentOS 7.32

Comment: Read `man rsyslog.conf` - it explains how to send logs to a remote server. You'll also have to configure the remote `rsyslogd` to accept logs from the netowrk.